# Putting dynamic sets of fields in form into JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a form that has a dynamic number of rows. Each row has 3 fields, a hidden id, code, and exchange.

```
<form id="form_in_question">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="id[]" value="123" />
                <input type="input" id="code[]" value="abc" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <select id="exchange[]">
                   <!-- Options... -->
               <select>
            <td>
        <tr>
        <!-- unlimited rows... -->
    </table>
</form>
```

I am trying to get an object that looks like:

```
data: {
    "0": {
            id: "123",
            code: "abc",
            exchange: "2"
         },
    "1": {
            id: "124",
            code: "bcd",
            exchange: "4"
         }
       }
```

So I can pass it a JSON object via AJAX like:

```
$("#dialogEditor").dialog('option', 'buttons', {'Save' : function() {
/* Define variables */
var data = $("#form_in_question").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.codes.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: "update_codes",
    entryId: entry,
    data: data
    },
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            success: function() {
    ui.showMsg("Codes Updated");
}
});
```

This is what the JSON looks like that I am actually passing:

```
data[0][name]   id[]
data[0][value]  
data[1][name]   code[]
data[1][value]  zxc
data[2][name]   exchange[]
data[2][value]  15
data[3][name]   id[]
data[3][value]  
data[4][name]   code[]
data[4][value]  BVA
data[5][name]   exchange[]
data[5][value]  5
```

or the raw data:
    action=update_codes&ResortId=12&data%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=id%5B%5D&data%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&data%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=code%5B%5D&data%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=zxc&data%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=exchange%5B%5D&data%5B2%5D%5Bvalue%5D=15&data%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=id%5B%5D&data%5B3%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&data%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=code%5B%5D&data%5B4%5D%5Bvalue%5D=BVA&data%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=exchange%5B%5D&data%5B5%5D%5Bvalue%5D=5

I tried a method I found on SO but it didn't group the 3 fields together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
var data = [];
var table = $("table").get()[0];

for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

    var tableRow = table.rows[i];
    var rowData = {};
    var inputData = {};

    inputData["id"] = $("input[id^='id']", $(tableRow.cells[1])).val();
    inputData["code"] = $("input[id^='code']", $(tableRow.cells[1])).val();
    inputData["exchange"] = $("select[id^='exchange']",$(tableRow.cells[2])).val();

    rowData[$(tableRow.cells[0]).text()] = inputData;

    data.push(rowData);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I only get the first row..I haven't had a chance to check out why that might be happening yet, I just wanted to say thanks for the help and update

Comment: Works for me - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/uM98R/8/). Note in your code above, the row did not have a closing `</tr>`.

Comment: I am getting `[{"0":{"code":"zxc"}},{"1":{}}]` when I run it in my code, so its definitely an issue there. I haven't had time to look at it today, had some other issues going on. I'll try to find the problem now. The html block above was extremely watered down from my actual code, so I must have chopped the `</tr>` out on accident. Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Got it, I had to work on a few things in the original code but that did it! thank you so much!